# export removes interface implementation from class in typeScript

Tags: typescript, class, interface, export

I have **.ts** file with **class declaration** and **.d.ts** file with **interface declaration**.

.ts file example:

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Jo";
  }
}
```

.d.ts file example:

```
interface A {
  name: string
}
```

So, the problem is - everything working fine, **class A auto detect interface A and implements it**.

But, when i add class **named export** or **default export**, like in example below - interface implementation disappearing, it's again clear class A.

```
export default class A {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Jo";
  }
}
```

or

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Jo";
  }
}
export { A }
```

Both variants leads to same problem - "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'A'".

If add interface to same file it will works, but i need this interface for global using and don't want to write same implementation directly in the class or same file.

So, what is going on and what should i do to make things right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put your code on a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzkhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmuAvrrhAB4AOA9lGMgCYR4AVwA2vBCLgUKaTLnwJOIKlCEIw3ABQBKOXnzIwAC2AUAdIRLIAvMgBEAKU52A3PORMcDIA) I get this error:

> class A
> Merged declaration 'A' cannot include a default export declaration. Consider adding a separate 'export default A' declaration instead.(2652)

And if you follow that advice:

```
interface A {
  name: string
}

class A {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Jo";
  }
}

export default A
```

It works as you expect [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=17&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzkhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmuAvrrggDZwUVqa74ID2IKlACuCMPygAKAJQ88+ZGAAWwCgDpCJZAF5kAIgBS-fQG5eyJjiu4IADwAOksMgAmEeCNYvUQA)

---

However, if the file that `class A` is in is Typescript, then you don't need the `.d.ts` file at all and you class should just be:

```
class A {
  name: string
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Jo";
  }
}
```

Which is it's own interface implicitly:

```
const a: A = { name: 'Foo' } // fine
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa0B2YC2BTAXNBAC4BOAlhgOarrAD2GJpArsMfaQBQCUit6aMQAW5CADoseaAF5oAIgBS9eQG4BAX1RaUqBk2LQwheHISYcBaAHIAYvXrXoGoA)

Comment: is it ok to import this class everywhere i need only this type?

Comment: Sure. You can also use import only the type with `import type { A } from './class-a'` if you don't need to the runtime constructor value.

Answer (score 1):

It's most unusual to write your interfaces in `.d.ts` files and to collide properties with a same-named class.

The idiomatic was to do this is to write the interface in one file:

```
export interface Nameable{
    name: string
}
```

and import it in another and use it correctly via the `implements` keyword:

```
import {Nameable} from './Nameable';

export class A implements Nameable{
    // etc
}
```

You can, of course, import the very same interface into any other file. Making things global rarely works out for the best.

Comment: I tried your variant, but ts still wants me to declare all fields in class again

Comment: @Mero Perhaps you are looking to **`extend`** an existing class that implements the `name` field, rather than `implement` an interface, which requires providing an impementation for the declared interface fields?

Comment: My point is to use one interface in diferent places of project, like class to implement and functions to declare incoming types etc.
Just looking for DRY solution, because ts wants me to declare this fields again in class that alreaddy implements this interface

Comment: @Mero That's my point. An `interface` isn't an implementation. If you want to share an implementation, `extend` a base class.